# How to get user specific data in a queue from ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

If as admin I wanted to know from a particular queue A, how many calls initiated by which person and how many get dequeued, and how many are still in queue @ any time.

I just want to develop one UI in my application to show those user-specific records from ActiveMQ.

Comment: Is there any ActiveMQ API available to get that info?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality in the broker that does this sort of thing.  You could develop your own broker plugin that tracks these things but you'd need to build some sort of DB or other storage as you would lose any in-memory stats when a broker is restarted.  You should use caution when trying to push all requirements into the message broker for system level management as that is not its purpose and will likely result in other issues when you do.